# What does <asp:Content> error mean in asp.net Master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, syntax-error

I am getting the Content controls error in my Master page. I did not leave any tag opened but still getting this error. Can somebody look at my code and point me to my mistake for correction? Can somebody explain me the error via this example?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Data.master" AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeFile="IMS.master.cs" Inherits="ims_IMS" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/AData.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contenttop" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" Runat="Server">
<div id="section-header" class="clear">
<h2 id="section-title">IMS </h2>
</div>
<de:PageSecurity ID="ps1" runat="server" ContentControlId="contentwrapper" AllowdeStaff="True" AllowTechss="False" AllowPeoples="False" AllowDistrict="True" ErrorMessage="You cannot access this page." />
<div id="section-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="sectioncontent" Runat="Server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving.

Comment: The page has one or more <asp:Content> controls that do not correspond with <asp: ContentPlaceHolder> controls in the Master Page.

Comment: so show us your master page.  Sounds like one or more of your CONTENTPLACEHOLDERIDs doesnt match one in the MASTERPAGE

Comment: That's my master page. As you can see the ContentPlaceHolder is tagged.

Comment: So all of your CONTENTPLACEHOLDERIDs match that those in the parent master page "~/Data.master"?

Comment: One last thing, where is your custom tag "de:PageSecurity" registered?

Comment: IF all this fails take out your MASTERTYPE tag.

Comment: @Steve I haven't checked them actually. Let me do that. de.page security is in the folder named controls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31415/discussion-between-steve-and-john)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you remove everything from inside `<asp:Content ID="Content3"` and see if you still get an error.

Also, try ending your custom control with `/>` instead of `/de>`

Comment: Did you try ending your custom control with /> instead of /de>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" xmlns:asp="#unknown"></asp:scriptmanager>

<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" text="Button" xmlns:asp="#unknown" />

<rsweb:reportviewer id="ReportViewer2" runat="server" height="261px" width="476px" xmlns:rsweb="#unknown"></rsweb:reportviewer>
```